# Find the function $y(x)$ that minimises $ \int_1^2{x^4[y''(x)]^2dx}$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

The problem I encounter is that:
find the function $y(x)$ with $y(1)=1$ $y'(1)=-2$ $y(2)=1/4$ and $y'(2)=-1/4 $ that minimises  $ \int_1^2{x^4[y''(x)]^2dx}.$

I know the equation I should use is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y''}=0.$$

In this case, I think the only remaining part is$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y''}$$

while $$\frac{d}{dx}(2x^4y'')=8x^3y''+2x^4y^{(3)}=0.$$

I think something is wrong with it, and I also don't know how to solve this differential equation.

Could anyone give me some advice on it? Thanks.

Comment: How can you minimize an integral that already has a fixed value?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I just edited it.

Comment: If you know the second derivative is $0$, then don't compute the derivative again. Just say that $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(2x^4y'') = 0 \implies 2x^4y'' = C_1x+C_2$$ and solve from there. You should get that $y$ is a function involving four arbitrary constants if you did it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Developping Ninad Munshi's comment, if $(2x^4y'')'' = 0$, then it means that $(2x^4y'')'$ is a constant, so that the successive integrations are (with $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ some constants) :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
   (2x^4y'')'' &=& 0 \\
   (2x^4y'')' &=& C_1 \\
   2x^4y'' &=& C_1x + C_2 \\
   y'' &=& \displaystyle \frac{C_1}{2x^3} + \frac{C_2}{2x^4} \\
   y' &=& \displaystyle -\frac{C_1}{4x^2} - \frac{C_2}{6x^3} + C_3 \\
   y &=& \displaystyle \frac{C_1}{4x} + \frac{C_2}{12x^2} + C_3x + C_4 \\
   y &=& \displaystyle Ax + B + \frac{C}{x} + \frac{D}{x^2}
\end{array}
$$
after relabelling the constants of integration, which you will determine thanks to the initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: This is not correct. Your fourth equation has a typo where the second term should be $\frac{C_2}{2x^4}$ instead of $\frac{C_2}{x}$. Also, the constants are arbitrary, so feel free to absorb factors and minus signs everywhere. For example, treat $$\int \frac{C_1}{x^3} \to \frac{C_1}{x^2}$$ instead of $-\frac{C_1}{2x^2}$, etc as the case may be.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  You're right, my bad, gone too quickly with this derivation. I'll correct it soon.